# Copy multiple word documents into one new word document

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, copy-paste

I am new in VBA and would like to asking some help.

I have a list of word document in excel in range B3:B40. I would like to copy the document in the list and paste to a new document without changing the page format.

I already tried the code below, it give me "run time error 13". Can anybody help with this situation?
Thanks in advance for any help.

```
Application.ScreenUpdating=false

set objword = createobject("Word.Application")
set objdoc = objword.Documents.Add
objword.visible = true

set objselection = objword.Selection
Folderpath = "C:\desktop"  'where I save the word document that would be combined

set objtempword = createobject("Word.Application")
set tempdoc = objword.documents.open (Folderpath & "\" & Sheet1.Range ("B3:B40")
set objtempselection = objtempword.selection
tempdoc.range.select
tempdoc.range.copy
objselection.typeparagraph
objselection.paste
tempdoc.close
```

Comment: IMHO, you have an unbalanced parenthesis after `("B3:B40"))`. Then, Why use a "range" ? Value of file should be in a single cell (B3) not a range (even if merged cells exist : select that cell and see name top left).

Answer (score 0):

I think this could work for you. What was missing is a cycle to work for each file (cell in the range).

```
Option Explicit

Sub JoinDocs()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim objword As Object, objdoc As Object, objselection   As Object
    Set objword = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set objdoc = objword.Documents.Add
    objword.Visible = True
    Dim Folderpath  As String
    Set objselection = objword.Selection
    Folderpath = "C:\desktop\"  'where I save the word document that would be combined
    Dim vDoc As Variant
    Dim objtempword As Object, tempdoc As Object, objtempselection As Object
    Set objtempword = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    For Each vDoc In Sheet1.Range("B3:B40").Value
        Set tempdoc = objword.Documents.Open(Folderpath & vDoc)
        Set objtempselection = objtempword.Selection
        tempdoc.Range.Select
        tempdoc.Range.Copy
        objselection.TypeParagraph
        objselection.Paste
        tempdoc.Close
    Next vDoc
End Sub
```